# Sharepoint Edit Form Error

Tags: forms, sharepoint-2010

I cant find a glue for that. Trying to edit a Listitem in the Browser , I get an Error the Log says:

File Not Found: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Layouts\EditingMenu\SiteAction.xml
System.ArgumentNullException: Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein.  Parametername: s    bei System.IO.StringReader..ctor(String s)     bei System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WorkflowUtilities.FlattenXmlToHashtable(String strXml)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WorkflowUtilities.DoesWorkflowCancelWhenItemEdited(String associationXml)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleDataSource.EnsurePageNotInLockingWorkflowIfInEditMode()     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleDataSource.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     bei System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     bei System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     bei System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     bei Sy... 489b3ebb-eb93-4172- SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
The Xml is in Place and Edit Forms for Other Lists in the same Web are working well ... Even Tried to make a new Editform ( and iisreset etc..)

Any Hint would be helpfull

Thanks Lars

Comment: to make it even more confusing , it still works for 3 very old entries, where a reqired lookup field wasn´t introduced. editing one of them makes them corrupt, reverting to first version still leaves them corrupt Change the Fields to be not required and make new Entries without them produces corrupt Items too I really have no idea ..

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown because the SharePoint 2010 expects that the AssociationData element contains a valid xml, where AssociationData element is a tag in Workflow Definition Schema. I've faced this issue after migrating our SP 2007 application to SP 2010. Unfortunately, it's not enough to just apply a valid xml to AssociationData element in your workflow definition:

It helps only for applications and workflow instances created/started after modifications have been made. Therefore, for live applications and started workflow instances we have to change AssociationData through the object model. I implemented the set of methods I described here - [SharePoint: Workflow + List Item Edit Form = Value cannot be null Exception](http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2012/04/sharepoint-workflow-list-item-edit-form-value-cannot-be-null-exception/). The basic methods are listed below:

```
public static void AdjustAssociationData(SPWorkflowAssociation workflowAssociation, SPWorkflowAssociationCollection collection)
{
    if (!IsValidXml(workflowAssociation.AssociationData))
    {
        string newValue = string.IsNullOrEmpty(workflowAssociation.AssociationData)
                                ? "<Data />"
                                : string.Format("<Data>{0}</Data>", workflowAssociation.AssociationData);
        workflowAssociation.AssociationData = newValue;
        collection.Update(workflowAssociation);
    }
}

public static bool IsValidXml(string str)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(str);
            return true;
        }
        catch {}
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, from my blog post mentioned above, you can download the console app I developed and used against our problem sp application.
I hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there was a Workflow for Disposition Approval attached to the Element Content type, not shure who placed it there, but anyways the Tasks could be found at the List. The Workflow was nerly invisible to me. The Error is odd and something I didnt expected

Lars